# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append' error when i tried to add list as value for a key in dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to do a program which tries to find whether a binary tree can be formed using the given input.

```
def main():
    children={}
    parents={}
    possible=True
    tup=input("enter the tuples seperated by commas")
    tup=tup.replace("(","")
    tup=tup.replace(")","")
    data=tup.split(" ")
    print(len(data))
    for x in range(0,len(data)):
        child,parent=data[x].split(",")
        if parent in parents :
            parents[parent].append()
        else:
            parents[parent]=child
        if len(parents[parent])>2:
           possible=False
           break
        if child in children:
            possible=False
            break
        else:
            children[child]=parent
        if possible==True:
            print("BINARY TREE POSSIBLE")
        else:
            print("BINARY TREE NOT POSIBLE")
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

The problem is with this line:

```
parents[parent].append()
```

at line 37 it says:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append' how to add list
> as a value for a key in dictionary in python

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to append something to the string that corresponds to the key 'parent'. In order to have a list as a value of a dict, you need to set the list as a value as you would do with for example a string.

`my_list[key] = ["item1", "item2"]`

Comment: hii thanks for the reply i solved the problem by adding parents[parent]=[] just before it enters loop.is there any other ways to do this